# What has a larger big-O: O(m^2n) or O(n^2)

Tags: performance, time, big-o

Given that m <= n, is O(n^2) in O(m^2n)? I know that O(mn) is in O(n^2) but I do not know what happens when you add the extra term

Comment: `O(mn)` is not `O(n^2)` if `m` is a constant independent of `n`.

Comment: @chepner OP is asking for subset-inclusion, not equality, I believe.

Comment: Is `m^2n` supposed to be `m^(2n)` or `(m^2)n`?

Comment: It is supposed to be (m^2)n.

Answer (score 0):

> Given that m <= n, is O(n^2) in O((m^2)n)

No, even if m grows with n.

Let m = sqrt(sqrt(n)).

O(n^2) is not contained in O((m^2)n) = O(((sqrt(sqrt(n)))^2)n) = O(sqrt(n)n)

Answer (score 0):

[n^2 vs (m^2)n](https://streamable.com/41vwib)

Even as m grows with n, and no matter the difference between m and n, n^2 will always be larger so (m^2)n would always be contained within n^2.